# Как поменять в фрагменте TextView из Активити?

Tags: android, android-fragment, textview, android-viewpager

Здравствуйте! По этой статье создал вкладки 
http://www.fandroid.info/android-material-design-rabota-s-vkladkami/

Все бы ничего, но как поменять из Активити TextView во фрагменте???

В самом фрагменте я написал

```
    TextView tvPage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView22);
    tvPage.setText("Текст");
```

Все работает, но как этот текст добавить из Активити с метода OnCreate или еще лучше если в самом Активити поменять этот текст

Полный исходный код:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

OneFragment.java

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one,  container, false);

   TextView tvPage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView22);
    tvPage.setText("Текст");



    return view;

}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="net.artsait.myapplication.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/one"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите поменять текст в момент создания фрагментов, то ваш код нужно изменить например вот так:

1. Переписать setupViewPager:

   ```
       private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
   ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

   Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
   bundle1.putString("text", "Это текст фрагмента 1");
   Fragment fragment = new OneFragment();
   fragment.setArguments(bundle1);
   adapter.addFragment(fragment, "ONE");

   Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
   fragment = new TwoFragment();
   bundle2.putString("text", "Это текст фрагмента 2");
   fragment.setArguments(bundle2);
   adapter.addFragment(fragment, "TWO");

   viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);}
   ```
2. Переписать onCreateView первого фрагмента "OneFragment":

   ```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
   TextView textView = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvOne));
   textView.setText(getArguments().getString("text"));

   return v;}
   ```
3. Переписать onCreateView второго фрагмента "TwoFragment":

   ```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
   TextView textView = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTwo));
   textView.setText(getArguments().getString("text"));

   return v;}
   ```

TextView переменные (их id) первого и второго фрагмента должны назваться

```
android:id="@+id/tvOne"
```

и

```
android:id="@+id/tvTwo"
```

В этом случае вы получите вот такую картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, я нашел уже решение через Bundle bundle = new Bundle
Я у тебя код не проверял, но примерно так я и сделал

Answer (score 2):

В фрагменте добавляете метод:

```
 public void setText(String item) {
        TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        view.setText(item);
    }
```

В MainActivity:

```
  // подключаем FragmentManager
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Получаем ссылку на фрагмент по ID
    Fragment2 fragment = (Fragment2) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);

// Сетим нужную информацию
if (fragment != null)
  fragment.setText("Некий текст");
```

Извиняюсь, возможно где то допустил ошибку, писал прямо  тут, но смысл думаю вы поняли.

Comment: findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);

Но в том то и дела, что нет id фрагмента,  есть id у ViewPager viewpager и id у самого текста.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще вот так. Менять текст в зависимости от выбранной вкладки.

1. В каждый фрагмент добавляем метод:

   ```
   public void setTextViewFragment(View v, String txt) {
       v.findViewById(R.id.detailsText).setText(txt);
   }
   ```
2. Также в MainActivity добавляем метод, который будет менять текст в зависимости от выбранной вкладки:

   ```
   private void setText() {

       int tabPosition = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
       Fragment fragment;
       View v;

       //В зависимости от позиции tabLayout, находим фрагмент и устанавливаем в нем текст
       if (tabPosition == 0) {
           fragment = ((ViewPagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter()).getItem(0);

           OneFragment oneFragment = (OneFragment) fragment;
           v = oneFragment.getView();

           if (v != null) {
               oneFragment.setTextViewFragment(v, "Выбрана вкладка 1 и фрагмент 1");
           }

       } 
       if (tabPosition == 1) {

           fragment = ((ViewPagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter()).getItem(1);

           TwoFragment twoFragment = (TwoFragment) fragment;
           v = twoFragment.getView();

           if (v != null) {
               twoFragment.setTextViewFragment(v, "Выбрана вкладка 2 и фрагмент 2");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Ну вроде код правильный, красным не где не подчеркнул, приложение не вылетела. Но текст фрагменте не изменился.
У Вас поменялся текст?

Comment: Или может я не так, что-то понял.

Я так понял метод setTextViewFragment () находится во фрагменте, но не в onCreateView, а что бы поменять что-то в лоятуе фрагмента, нам нужно написать код в onCreateView.

Что касается второго метода setText() который находиться в активити. Его ведь надо еще как-то запустить? Я дописал в onCreate строку setText();, но все равно ничего не понменялось

Comment: Текст у вас не меняется, так как View фрагмента еще не создано (когда в Activity вы вызываете setText()) соответственно метод setTextViewFragment() не происходит и текст не меняется.

Comment: См. еще один вариант ответа выше. Используйте его, если надо поменять текст в момент создания фрагментов. Тот пример, который привел я ранее, касается случая, когда надо поменять текст в уже созданных фрагментах, например при смене вкладки (нажатия кнопки и т.д.)